# Relation between degree $[K_2 \colon K_1]$ of extension and degree $[FK_2 \colon FK_1]$ of extension after compositing

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

Suppose we have number fields $F, K_1,$ and $K_2$ with $K_1 \subseteq K_2$, all Galois over a base field $K$. We then have

$$ [FK_2 : K_1] = [FK_2 : FK_1] \cdot [FK_1 : K_1], \text{ and} $$

$$ [FK_2 : K_1] = [FK_2 : K_2] \cdot [K_2 : K_1], $$

where $FK_i$ denotes the compositum of $F$ and $K_i$. The above provides

$$ [K_2 : K_1] = [FK_2 : FK_1] \cdot \dfrac{[FK_1 : K_1]}{[FK_2 : K_2]}. $$

Are there obvious sufficient/necessary conditions to provide a relation (inequality or, preferably, divisibility) between the degrees $[FK_2 : FK_1]$ and $[K_2 : K_1]$? From the above, it would be equivalent to provide such a relation between the degrees $[FK_i : K_i]$ for $i=1,2$. I'm curious about what can be said more generally, even potentially beyond the assumptions of Galois number fields as stated here, but should linear disjointness of $F$ with $K_1$ and $K_2$ over $K$ be enough to provide divisibility (or even equality?) of these degrees? Any help or a useful reference would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you assume that everything is Galois and $F$ and $K_2$ are linearly disjoint, which implies that $F$ and $K_1$ are linearly disjoint too, then equality holds. In fact, the following standard fact of Galois theory holds (see for example Milne's notes, Proposition 3.18):

if $E,L$ are extensions of a field $K$ and $E/K$ is Galois, then $EL/L$ is Galois and its Galois group is isomorphic to that of $E/E\cap L$.

Now suppose that $F\cap K_2=K$. I claim that it follows that $FK_1\cap K_2=K_1$. In fact, suppose that $FK_1\cap K_2=K_3$. By the proposition $[FK_2:K_2]=[FK_1:K_3]$, but also $[FK_1:K_3]=[FK_3:K_3]=[F:K]$ and $[F:K]=[FK_1:K_1]$. It follows that $K_1=K_3$.

Now to prove your claim just apply the proposition to $E=FK_1$ and $L=K_2$.

Comment: Thanks, especially for the reference! That standard fact is precisely what I was trying to use, so definitely good I have a specific reference in mind for it now :)