# Degree of composite of both fields

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

Given three fields $F,K$ and $L$ with $F\subseteq K$, one has that $[LK:LF] \leq [K:F]$, where $LK$ and $LF$ are composite fields. Is this also a divisibility? For example, if $L$ and $K$ are extensions of $F$ with $K/F$ Galois and $L$ and $K$ linearly disjoint over $F$, then this is equality. Thanks!

Comment: You mean [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4360274/relation-between-degree-k-2-colon-k-1-of-extension-and-degree-fk-2-colon?rq=1)?

Comment: Yes! But without the Galois and linear disjointedness assumptions, can we say any more about this inequality?

Comment: Try with $F=\Bbb{Q}, K=\Bbb{Q}(2^{1/3})$, $L=\Bbb{Q}(e^{2i\pi/3} 2^{1/3})$. Unrelated but note that if $K/F$ is Galois then $Gal(LK/LF)$ is a subgroup of $Gal(K/F)$ so that $[LK:LF]$ divides $[K:F]$.